# DatePicker is not working properly in jqgrid edit form/inline editing while called from .load method of jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Problem : DatePicker is not hided after I choose any date in jqgrid edit/AddInline Edit form. this is not go away even I press escape or press close button.

grid.html called from index.html page, when clicked on the date columns, datepicker appeared but dont go away after selecting the dates.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>main document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/redmond_1.10.4/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid-4.6.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <style type="text">
        .ui-datepicker {z-index:1200;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/grid.locale-en-4.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min-4.6.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#submenu').on('click','a#subdailyformentry', function() {
                    $("#contents").html("<div align='center'><img src='Images/ajax_call.gif'/></div>");
                    $("#contents").load("./grid.html");
                });
            });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id ="submenu" align="left" style="margin:5px auto 5px auto;width:80%;height:20px;padding:10px;"> 
    <a href="#" name ="subdailyformentry" id="subdailyformentry">Daily Form Entry..</a>
    </div>
    <div id="contents" class="ui-corner-all lavaLampBottomStyleWithoutBorder" style="margin:auto ;width:80%;height:400px; border:#039 solid 1px;">   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

grid.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/q/14318014/315935</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        /*global $ */
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var mydata = [
                    {id: "12345", name: "Desktop Computer", note: "note",      stock: "Yes", ship: "FE", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "23456", name: "Laptop",           note: "Long text", stock: "Yes", ship: "IN", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "34567", name: "LCD Monitor",      note: "note3",     stock: "Yes", ship: "TN", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "45678", name: "Speakers",         note: "note",      stock: "No",  ship: "AR", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "56789", name: "Laser Printer",    note: "note2",     stock: "Yes", ship: "FE", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "67890", name: "Play Station",     note: "note3",     stock: "No",  ship: "FE", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "76543", name: "MobileTelephone",  note: "note",      stock: "Yes", ship: "AR", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "87654", name: "Server",           note: "note2",     stock: "Yes", ship: "TN", sdate: "2007-12-03"},
                    {id: "98765", name: "Matrix Printer",   note: "note3",     stock: "No",  ship: "FE", sdate: "2007-12-03"}
                ],
                $grid = $("#rowed6"),
                initDate = function (elem) {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                        //autoSize: true,
                        defaultDate: new Date(2007, 11, 3),
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true,
                        onSelect: function () {
                            var $grid, grid;
                            if (typeof (elem.id) === "string" && elem.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                                $grid = $(elem).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
                                            .next("div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv")
                                            .find("table.ui-jqgrid-btable:first");
                                if ($grid.length > 0) {
                                    grid = $grid[0];
                                    if ($.isFunction(grid.triggerToolbar)) {
                                        grid.triggerToolbar();
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                // to refresh the filter
                                $(elem).trigger("change");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                dateTemplate = {align: "center", sorttype: "date", width: 94,
                    editrules: { date: true }, editoptions: { dataInit: initDate },
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"],
                        attr: { maxlength: 10, size: 11 }, // for searching toolbar
                        maxlength: 10, size: 11, // for searching dialog
                        dataInit: initDate
                    },
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Short", newformat: "Y-m-d" }},
                lastsel3;

            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                data: mydata,
                colNames: ["Last Sales", "Name", "Stock", "Ship via", "Notes"],
                colModel: [
                    { name: "sdate", template: dateTemplate },
                    { name: "name", width: 115, editoptions: {maxlength: "30"} },
                    { name: "stock", width: 70, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",
                        edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"},
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;true:Yes;false:No" } },
                    { name: "ship", width: 105, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: "select",
                        edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX", defaultValue: "AR" },
                        stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
                        value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX" } },
                    { name: "note", width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea" }
                ],
                cmTemplate: {editable: true},
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 100],
                pager: "#pager",
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: false,
                viewrecords: true,
                sortname: "sdate",
                sortorder: "desc",
                height: "100%",
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel3) {
                        $(this).jqGrid("restoreRow", lastsel3);
                        $(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, true);
                        lastsel3 = id;
                    }
                },
                editurl: "/MyServletNameHere",
                caption: "Date Picker Integration"
            });
            $.extend($.jgrid.search, {
                recreateFilter: true,
                multipleSearch: true,
                multipleGroup: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterSearch: true,
                overlay: 0,
                searchOnEnter: true
            });

            $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, edit: false, del: false});
            $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {defaultSearch: "cn", stringResult: true});
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="rowed6"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise what can be done to work datepicker correctly.

Comment: hello maninder ,provide some code

Comment: Hello @PratikJoshi, I added two files code as per your advise. I can upload the stuff in zip folder. if this is permitted. Thanks

Comment: Can any one suggest about the solution please